# can't install alamofire 1.3 using cocoapods

Tags: alamofire

Hello i have a issue trying use alamofire 1.3, i need this because my projects wasn't migrated to swift 2.0, so here is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
     pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
end
```

But always get this error:

*Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Alamofire (~> 1.3)` required by `Podfile`*

Any idea?

Comment: Go to cocoadpods.org and search Alamofire. If you copy the proposed podline should be: pod 'Alamofire', '3.0.0-beta.3'

Comment: Yep, but alamofire is there, actually did at terminal : pod search Alamofire, and is there, but can't install.
I tried last version to this that you sad, but at search, version 1.3 is there to, no one version is working, last or old. 
Is just i delete alamofire pod from pod install and pod install work

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Alamofire with CocoaPods with a deployment target of 7.0. It MUST be 8.0+. The reason for this is that Swift frameworks are not supported on iOS 7.